# how to convert json array to float array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to take data from json array ,, i want to make regular float array for my barchart .. but how to change json array to float array

```
public class fragment extends Fragment {
public fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


final static String TAG = "ok";

BarChart barChart;

float datay [];
float datay1 [];
String datax [];
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    barChart = (BarChart)fragment.findViewById(R.id.barchart);

    fetchData();


    return  fragment;
}

public void fetchData(){
    showLoading("Loading");
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.CHART, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            hideLoading();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG,"ini response"+response);
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                //datacatagory for datax
                JSONArray datacatagory = object.getJSONArray("category");
                Log.d(TAG,"catagory"+datacatagory);
                JSONArray jdata1 = object.getJSONArray("data");
                Log.d(TAG,"jdata"+jdata1);
                JSONObject obj1 = jdata1.getJSONObject(1);
                Log.d(TAG,"obj"+obj1);
                // arr1 for datay
                JSONArray arr1 = obj1.getJSONArray("data");
                Log.d(TAG,"arr"+arr1);
                //arr2 for datay1
                JSONArray arr2 = obj1.getJSONArray("data");
                Log.d(TAG,"arr"+arr1);

                //how convert data jsonarray to regular array in java??

                chartListener(datay,datax,datay1);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            getToast(error.getMessage());
            hideLoading();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            return getPOST("laba_rugi");
        }

    };

    addRequestQueen(strReq,TAG);

}


public void chartListener(float datay[],String datax[],float data1[]){
    barChart.setDescription("ok");
    ArrayList<BarEntry> ydata = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0;i< datay.length;i++){
        ydata.add(new BarEntry(datay[i],i));
    }

    ArrayList<BarEntry> ydata1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0;i< datay.length;i++){
        ydata1.add(new BarEntry(data1[i],i));
    }

    ArrayList<String> xdata = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0;i < datax.length;i++){
        xdata.add(datax[i]);
    }

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(ydata,"rugi");
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(ydata1,"laba");
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
    dataSets.add(barDataSet);
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);

    BarData barData = new BarData(xdata,dataSets);
    barData.setValueTextSize(13f);
    barData.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    int a =00000;
    barChart.setData(barData);
    barChart.setBackgroundColor(a);
    barChart.invalidate();
}
}
```

I want to take data from json array, i want to make regular float array for my barchart. But, how to change json array to float array
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple method should help you. Not tested, but should work.

```
private float[] fillData(JSONArray jsonArray){

    float[] fData = new float[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            fData[i] = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getString(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return fData;
}
```

Just write this method like this, and get float array:

```
JSONArray arr1 = obj1.getJSONArray("data");
float[] data = fillData(arr1);
```

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand please give me direct example to float datay [];

Comment: Which data would you like to change to float data? @Said

Comment: JSONArray arr1 This is what I want to change to float datay[];

Comment: Please share this log also "Log.d(TAG,"arr"+arr1);" @Said

Comment: ok.. this my log.. [32.534,46.436,0,6.565,0,7,7.777,77.457,4,0,63.463,3.453,0,0,3.453,253,0,0,4.535,0,34.543,0,55,646,0,56.565,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: How i change it to its float datay[]; @JavadKhan

Comment: @Said you can test before asking)))

Comment: Thank you very much .. succeed .. but what if the data I change to string

Comment: @Said if you change your JSONArray data to string, you should split to String array, then you should parse to Float each one. But my method is easy way. You can use this. You Are Welcome!